# Google map direction using lat/lon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have lat/lon for 2 places. How to get directions from google maps api?
I want to show map and directions text.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var myOptions = {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var start = '37.7683909618184, -122.51089453697205';
    var end = '41.850033, -87.6500523';
    var request = {
      origin:start, 
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var myRoute = response.routes[0];
        var txtDir = '';
        for (var i=0; i<myRoute.legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
          txtDir += myRoute.legs[0].steps[i].instructions+"<br />";
        }
        document.getElementById('directions').innerHTML = txtDir;
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="directions" style="width:500px;height:500px;float:left"></div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Or using the previous code :

```
…
var start = new google.maps.LatLng('37.7683909618184', '-122.51089453697205');
var end = new google.maps.LatLng('41.850033', '-87.6500523');
var request = {
  origin:start, 
  destination:end,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   …
}
…
```

This way the coordinates are directly recognized as such, and not evaluated from string.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution: pass an object like to origin and destination

```
{lat: 39.904309, lng: 116.385871}
```